# Are Amazighs the inventors of the so called Arabic numerals?

Tags: science

From [this link](http://www.algerie-dz.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-7625.html), I read that an Algerian professor published a thesis where he stated that what we call Arabic numerals are not Arabic as they have been invented and used for the first time in [Bejaia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9ja%C3%AFa) which was (and still is) a pure [Amazigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berbers) (not Arabic) region in North of Algeria.

Note that **Arabs of today use Indian numerals instead** which this may also explain their rejection of Arabic numerals as they have been invented (at least in their actual form) in Bejaia.

Original publication is this:    [A. Boucenna: ON THE ORIGIN OF  THE ARABIC NUMERALS](http://xxx.lanl.gov/ftp/math/papers/0304/0304219.pdf)

Is this true?

Comment: What we call "Arabic" numerals [originated in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system#Symbols). It spread west and reached [Bugia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9ja%C3%AFa), from where [Leonardo Fibonnaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) picked up the system and transmitted it to Europe. Based on some selective interpretation of these facts one might be able to reason that it was "invented and used for the first time" in Béjaïa, but not really.

Comment: Amazighing! Was the professor a Bejaiarian? Are you the "professor"?

Comment: direct link to the paper: http://xxx.lanl.gov/ftp/math/papers/0304/0304219.pdf

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes, that's the publication, thank you. No, I am not that professor :)

Comment: Well the thesis of this publication is based on books written in the 19th Century, while Fibonacci has been there in the 12th Century as far as i can see!

Answer (score 3):

Arabic numerals were originally of many different variant forms. Even in Europe, early examples vary considerably from one another. The popular form that evolved was most heavily influenced by the work [Liber Abaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Abaci) (1202) by [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci). Fibonacci learned these digits while he was growing up in Bugia (now [Béjaïa, Algeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9ja%C3%AFa)). Therefore, as the paper says, the form of the digits he used was typical of Bejaia.

Comment: Just to clarify, while he learned the local variant in use in Bejaia at the time, the positional decimal number system itself actually originated more than a millennium earlier in India, not North Africa.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm sorry to disagree but Indian numerals are different. Arabs today use Indian numerals because what we call Arabic numerals were apparently used for the first time in Bejaia only (at least in their actual form)

Comment: @Begueradj - That's not a disagreement. The form of the actual glyphs used is a very different issue than the idea of a positional decimal number system itself.